# Problem getting Cypress to play nice with StencilJS components

Tags: cypress, stenciljs

I am experiencing some flaky behavior with Cypress tests against my Angular application: they work fine when targeting my local box but when setting `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` to a remote machine running the same code, then some of the tests fail.

I think I have narrowed this down to the interaction of StencilJS components. Consider: I have one form that asks for username, password, etc., using regular `<input>` elements, to wit:

```
<input formControlName="username" type="text">
```

...and so forth. The tests work reliably with those, meaning these  statements correctly fill in the fields:

```
cy.get('[formControlName=fullname]').type(name)
cy.get('[formControlName=username]').type(username)
cy.get('[formControlName=password]').type(passwrod)
```

I have another form that uses a StencilJS component which has an embedded `<input>`, so the elements look like this:

```
<my-input ngDefaultControl formControlName="newPassword" type="password"></my-input>
<my-input ngDefaultControl formControlName="confirmPassword" type="password"></my-input>
```

My code then attempts to fill in the two fields:

```
cy.get('[formControlName=newPassword]').find('input').type(updated_password).blur()
cy.get('[formControlName=confirmPassword]').find('input').type(updated_password).blur()
```

But here the test fails: what it actually does is fill in the first password, advance to the second field and fill in the second--but then the first field mysteriously becomes blank!

The Stencil component is a simple wrapper around an `<input>`:

```
return (
  <input type={ this.type }
    value={ this.value }
    placeholder={ this.placeholder }
    onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) }></input>
);
```

I have tried with and without `.blur()`.
I have tried with and without chaining with `.then()`.
But the above test always fails with a remote target and always succeeds with a local target machine.
Any other suggestions on how to make this work reliably?

Comment: Have you tried sending keyboard events one by one with `cy.get('[formControlName=newPassword]').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 999, which: 999 })`

Comment: It may have to something Cypress is not supported shadow root correctly?
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/144